# com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.ChameleonRenderKitFactory

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, weblogic12c

I am using JSF 1.2 with RichFaces3.3.3 in weblogic 12C server. As 12c provides support for JSF 2 by default, i have added JSF related packeges in prefer-application packages in weblogic.xml. I am getting below exception.

```
<Feb 24, 2016 5:18:42 PM IST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener failed: com.sun.faces.config
.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.ChameleonRenderKitFactory.
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.ChameleonRenderKitFactory
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:214)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:200)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:678)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
```

Comment: <Feb 24, 2016 5:31:42 PM IST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener failed: com.sun.faces.config
.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.ChameleonRenderKitFactory.
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.ChameleonRenderKitFactory
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:214)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:200)

Comment: Probably you should remove JSF 2 related jars and use JSF 1.2  + RichFaces jars (and proper faces-config.xml and web.xml)